# Calculating the tangent bundle of $O(m)$ and $SL(m)$.

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, tangent-bundle

I want to show that

> (a) $TO(m) = \{(M,MA) \mid M \in O(m), A \in T_{Id}O(m)\}$

and

> (b) $TSL(m) = \{(M,MA) \mid M \in SL(m), A \in T_{Id}SL(m)\}.$

By definition, $TX = \{(x,y) \mid x \in X, y \in T_xX\}$.

---

For (a),
$$T_{M}O(m) = \{H \mid H^tM + HM^t = 0\}.$$
I can show that
$\{MA \mid M \in O(m), A \in T_{Id}O(m)\} \subset T_MO(m)$. Is possible to show that this sets are equal? If yes, then the problem is solved.

For (b),
$$T_{Id}SL(m) = \{A \mid tr{A} = 0\},$$
but I could not to figure out $T_M SL(m)$. My idea is also to show that $\{MA \mid M \in SL(m), A \in T_{Id}SL(m)\}$.

---

I'm beginner in Differential Geometry. So, if there are better ways to do that, I would like to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  For any of these matrix groups $G$, $T_M G = \{ MA \mid A \in T_I G\}$.  That's why we study carefully the tangent space to the identity.  It's called the *Lie algebra* of $G$.  It “sees” a lot of the properties of $G$, but has the advantage of being a vector space.

Comment: Nice. Do you have some hints to find $T_{M}SL(m)$?

Comment: @Greg If $f : M \rightarrow N$ is a smooth map and $d_{p}f \neq 0$ for all $p \in S : = f^{-1}(\{ q\})$, then $S$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$ of codimension $\dim N$. Moreover, after identifying $T_{p} S$ as a subspace of $T_{p} M$, one has $T_{p} S = \ker d_{p} f$. This is pretty easy to calculate for $\operatorname{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ because it is a level set of $\det : \operatorname{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think I can prove that for matrix groups, $T_{M}G = MT_{id}(G)$ using the translation $x \mapsto gx$.

Comment: That's right, @Greg, because for matrix groups $D(L_M) = L_M$ in an obvious way.